# Export ImageCollections by periods in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2

I am working with Sentinel-2 data in GEE from the JavaScript API. I need to perform a chain of simple processes (including: search, pixel masking, band selection) and then export to my Drive. I need to perform this process for several periods of time (actually months) and save each `FeatureCollection` in a folder. These periods are listed below:

```
var periods = ee.List([
              ee.DateRange('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31'),
              ee.DateRange('2019-02-01', '2019-02-28'),
              ee.DateRange('2019-03-01', '2019-03-31')]);
```

I am able to carry out the process successfully for a single period:

```
var period1 = ee.DateRange('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31');

// Import and filter Sentinel-2 data.
var s2_data = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
                                .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 80)
                                .filterDate(period1)
                                .filterBounds(extent);

// Generate 'clear_sky' Sentinel-2 images using SCL.
var s2_clear_sky = function(image){
  var scl = image.select('SCL');
  var clear_sky_pixels = scl.eq(4).or(scl.eq(5)).or(scl.eq(6)).or(scl.eq(11));
  return image.updateMask(clear_sky_pixels);
};
var s2_data = s2_data.map(s2_clear_sky);
var s2_data_exp = s2_data.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4']);

// Export data to drive
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(s2_data_exp, '2019-01-01_2019-01-31', 
                {scale: 10, 
                 region: extent, 
                 type: 'float'});
```

However I don't know how I can do this for all my periods in the `periods` list.

I am facing two main problems:

1. How to apply the process for all the `ee.DateRange` of the `periods` list.
2. How to send each period in the form of `ee.String` to the `batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive` function.

I apologize in advance if my approach is not adequate to deal with the problem. I am new to GEE. Could anyone please assist me on upgrading the code?

I found this related issue but I can't understand: [ImageCollection Exporting by years](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287190/imagecollection-exporting-by-years)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a client-side object instead of server-side objects like `ee.List` and `ee.DateRange`, you can simply iterate your periods client-side and use client-side operations to generate your folder name based on each period. You can read up on this in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).

You do get some warnings outputted by `batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive`, but that's not something I can debug. You already got those with your original script.

Note that there will be quite a few click to submit all your tasks.

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')
  
var extent = Map.getBounds(true)
var periods = [
  ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-31'],
  ['2019-02-01', '2019-02-28'],
  ['2019-03-01', '2019-03-31']
]

periods.forEach(exportPeriod)

function exportPeriod(period) {
  // Import and filter Sentinel-2 data.
  var s2_data = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 80)
    .filterDate(period[0], period[1])
    .filterBounds(extent)
  
  // Generate 'clear_sky' Sentinel-2 images using SCL.
  var s2_clear_sky = function(image) {
    var scl = image.select('SCL')
    var clear_sky_pixels = scl.eq(4).or(scl.eq(5)).or(scl.eq(6)).or(scl.eq(11))
    return image.updateMask(clear_sky_pixels)
  }
  var s2_data = s2_data.map(s2_clear_sky)
  var s2_data_exp = s2_data.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4'])
  var folder = period[0] + '_' + period[1]
  // Export data to drive
  batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(s2_data_exp, folder, {
    scale: 10,
    region: extent,
    type: 'float'
  })
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/34b89729f0d7864ac283c4203e1a3701